# How to pass a object in a object in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, properties, postman

So I am working on a Vue project with a Rest API and I am struggling setting an object inside an object.

**My vue page**

```
<template>
  <div class="submit-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Party Name</label>
        <input
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            required
            v-model="party.name"
            name="name"
        />
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input
            class="form-control"
            id="description"
            required
            v-model="party.description"
            name="description"
        />
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PartyLeaderName">PartyLeader Name</label>
      <input
          class="form-control"
          id="partyLeaderName"
          required
          v-model="party.partyLeaderName"
          name="partyLeaderName"
      />
    </div>

      <button @click="saveParty" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <p>{{message}}</p>

<!--    <div>-->
<!--      <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newParty">Add</button>-->
<!--    </div>-->
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import PartyDataService from "@/services/PartyDataService";
import PartyLeaderDataService from "../../services/PartyLeaderDataService";

export default {
  name: "AddParty",
  data() {
    return {
      party: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        ispartynational: true,
        partyLeader:{}
      },
      message:""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveParty() {
      var data = {
        name: this.party.name,
        description: this.party.description,
        ispartynational: true,
        partyLeader: this.party.partyLeader
      };
      PartyLeaderDataService.findByName("Marije")
          .then(response => {
            this.party.partyLeader = response.data.partyLeader;
            console.log(response.data);//partyleader json correct
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      console.log(data)
      PartyDataService.create(data)
          .then(response => {
            this.party.id = response.data.id;
            console.log(response.data);
            this.message = 'The Party was created successfully!';
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });

    },
    newParty() {
      this.party = {};
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.submit-form {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;}

</style>
```

The problem is that in this part of the code:

```
data() {
    return {
      party: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        ispartynational: true,
        partyLeader:{}
      },
```

the data should be formatted like this:
[image]

It is all formatted properly the case except for the partyLeader property, this will not set like in the postman example.
I already got the following code working:

```
  PartyLeaderDataService.findByName("Marije")
      .then(response => {
        this.party.partyLeader = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);//partyleader json correct
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

My console log shows me the output of this piece of code is like this:

```
{id: 6, name: "Marije", appearance: "Link"}
```

Which is what I want. The problem now is how do I get this to the partyLeader property?
Thanks in advance!

**Added**

When I change the code to this:

```
  PartyLeaderDataService.findByName("Marije")
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)  //{id: 6, name: "Marije", appearance: "Link"}
            this.party.partyLeader = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);  //{__ob__: Observer}
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
```

I have no idea why

**Update**

So now I have it so that the output is this:
[image: Current output]

But it seems that is not the same as this:

```
 {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Visual",
        "description": "new party",
        "ispartynational": true,
        "partyLeader": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Marijke",
            "appearance": "Link of image"
        }
 }
```

How do I make it so that it is like the postman formatted(Only the partyLeader is wrong formatted)?

Comment: You currently have `partyLeader:[]` as array, chnage it to `partyLeader:{}` first. Then try logging to console the value of `this.party.partyLeader`.

Comment: `this.party.partyLeader.push(response.data)`

Comment: Hi, You are using `response.data.partyLeader` to set the value, but in console.log you are using `response.data`.

Comment: When I do that my object partyleader changes to the following: {__ob__: Observer}

Comment: @MatJ I added the problem I got in the post!

Comment: @YashMaheshwari did that and added the problem in the post!

Comment: Try a simple: ```this.party.partyLeader = Object.assign({}, response.data)```

Comment: Also, since this is an assignement of object, the references of this.party.partyLeader and reponse.data might become the same after the assignement. Which explains why in the second console.log shows an Observable, which is a way that vue.js handles reactivity. 
You should instead of assigning directly, copy the object using one of the many methods to do so.

Comment: Also why do you even need a var data at the start of saveParty()? And having another look if you call saveParty() after calling newParty() you are going to have an exception

Comment: The code works fine as-is, I replicated it on stackoverflow snippets. Unless you had the `response.data.partyLeader` as a typo, which might have caused the issue.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I updated the post to the new problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value of `this.party.partyLeader` equal to `response.data`, it becomes Observable. To instead set the value of `this.party.partyLeader` to simply be the current value of `response.data`, try creating a new object using the spread operator as follows:

`this.party.partyLeader = {...response.data};`

Comment: Actually, given the code, response.data doesn't seem to be the Observable, it becomes one after linking it to the data 'this.party.partyLeader' which makes it one. 
But aside from that this should be the right solution.

Comment: Thanks, Zakaria. I updated my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: When I try this I get the following log:
{name: "D666", description: "s", ispartynational: true, partyLeader: Array(0)}
description: "s"
ispartynational: true
name: "D666"
partyLeader: Array(0)
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
__proto__: Object

The partyLeader array is empty!

Comment: How about this, @LardinoisJosse: `this.party.partyLeader = {...response.data.partyLeader}`

Comment: Nope same outcome

Comment: @MichaelPrather I changed the code a bit. Can you perhaps help me with the updated problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the implementation of the `PartyLeaderDataService.findByName` method?